# ITextSharp: How to get an image embedded resource

Tags: c#, itext, embedded-resource

I'm parsing an HTML with some images inside this.

This images are stored as embedded resource, not in the filesystem.

as I know, i need to set a custom image provider in HtmlPipelineContext, and this provider need to retrieve the image path or the itextsharp image.

The question is, somebody know which method of Abstract Image Provider i need to implement? and how?

this is my code:

```
            var list = new List<string> { text };
            byte[] renderedBuffer;
            using (var outputMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (
                    var pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30))
                {
                    var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, outputMemoryStream);
                    pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
                    pdfDocument.Open();
                    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(new CssAppliersImpl());
                    htmlContext.SetImageProvider(new MyImageProvider());
                    htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
                    ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(true);
                    CssResolverPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(pdfDocument, pdfWriter)));
                    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
                    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
                    foreach (var htmlText in list)
                    {
                        using (var htmlViewReader = new StringReader(htmlText))
                        {
                            p.Parse(htmlViewReader);
                        }
                    }
                }

                renderedBuffer = new byte[outputMemoryStream.Position];
                outputMemoryStream.Position = 0;
                outputMemoryStream.Read(renderedBuffer, 0, renderedBuffer.Length);
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a custom Image Provider it doesn't seem to be supported. The only thing it really supports is changing root paths.

However, here's one solution to the problem:

Create a new html tag, called `<resimg src="{resource name}"/>`, and write a custom tag processor for it.

Here's the implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Our custom HTML Tag to add an IElement.
/// </summary>
public class ResourceImageHtmlTagProcessor : AbstractTagProcessor
{
    public override IList<IElement> End(IWorkerContext ctx, Tag tag, IList<IElement> currentContent)
    {
        var src = tag.Attributes["src"];
        var bitmap = (Bitmap)Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(src);

        if (bitmap == null)
            throw new RuntimeWorkerException("No resource with the name: " + src);

        var converter = new ImageConverter();
        var image = Image.GetInstance((byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bitmap, typeof(byte[])));
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlPipelineContext = this.GetHtmlPipelineContext(ctx);
        return new List<IElement>(1)
            {
                this.GetCssAppliers().Apply(
                    new Chunk((Image)this.GetCssAppliers().Apply(image, tag, htmlPipelineContext), 0f, 0f, true),
                    tag,
                    htmlPipelineContext)
            };
    }
}
```

To configure your new processor replace the line where you specify the TagFactory with the following:

```
var tagProcessorFactory = Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
tagProcessorFactory.AddProcessor(new ResourceImageHtmlTagProcessor(), new[] { "resimg" });
htmlContext.SetTagFactory(tagProcessorFactory);
```